# I am making a nav bar. And I want to use jscript to add a active class to the nav element.depending on the url

Tags: javascript, uinavigationbar

I think i should use the window.location.pathname to get the url. and store in a var called page_name

then i want to say, if the windows.location.pathname is in the url bar, then add active class to my

here is what i have so far. let me know what i need to change.

```
<div class="nav-collapse">
   <ul id="nav" class="nav">
   <li id="home"><a href="home_page.php">Home</a></li>
   <li id="watch"><a href="watch.php">Watch</a></li>    
   </ul>
 </div>
```

---

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var page_name = window.location.pathname.substring(1);
$('li[href$="' + page_name + '"]').addClass('active');
});
```

Comment: try $('a[href$=' + page_name + ']').parent() , assuming markup is <li><a ... ></li>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you ask why your script doesn't work, then I assume that your jquery selector is wrong. Try this:
nav.js:

```
$(function(){
    // get only the file name of the location pathname
    var page_name = window.location.pathname.split('/').pop();
    // now add 'active' class to the li element:
    $('a[href$="' + page_name + '"]').parent().addClass('active');
});
```

common.css:

```
.active {
background-color: red;
}
```

{home_page, watch}.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="common.css">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="nav-collapse">
            <ul id="nav" class="nav">
                <li id="home">
                    <a href="home_page.html">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li id="watch">
                    <a href="watch.html">Watch</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="nav.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: this is not working either. when i use your code. it doesnt add the class to a. also, i would prefer to have the class changed on li instead of on a. because i have my css active class set up for li

Comment: I enhanced my example. Please consider that I select the a tag with the right href and then I navigate to the parent li element.